# Android: Real Time Resizing Bitmaps

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, android-image

I know this question has been asked to death, but I'm somewhat confused about the answers I've been seeing. So I want to resize a bitmap I am displaying on the screen in my android app. I need to be able to resize it efficiently, in real time. It is expected for the user to be constantly resizing / panning around the image, so I want to do this as efficiently as possible.

So far, I've only seen `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(...)` which seems like its completely rebuilding the bitmap. It gets a bit of lag when the user is performing pinch and zoom (many resizes in a row).

Whats weird is that when I tried using `canvas.scale(...)`, there was no lag in zooming the image. The only problem with this is that it resizes the coordinates as well, making it impossible to use in this application. Is there something similar to `canvas.scale()` for Bitmaps, that just scale the image without reloading it, similar to `canvas.scale()`?

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the Canvas methods [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html).
What you are after is probably a combination of `Canvas.scale(...)` and the [`Canvas.save()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#save%28%29)/[`Canvas.restore()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#restore%28%29) methods to reset the coordinates after drawing.

If this is not what you are looking for, another solution *might* be to [get the current transformation matrix](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#getMatrix%28%29) and apply to your coordinates to get the 'currently active' coordinates.